# Trouble at connection with mysql - xampp

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, xampp

I use XAMPP for linux in Ubuntu 14.04. When I start the service on terminal, prints the next logs:

> sudo /opt/lampp/lampp start
>
> "Starting XAMPP for Linux 5.5.30-0...
>
> XAMPP: Starting Apache...ok.
>
> XAMPP: Starting MySQL...already running.
>
> XAMPP: Starting ProFTPD...ok."

I don't know why MySQL service appears already running when I start XAMPPm at first time...But that's not the only trouble...

When I go to localhost/phpmyadmin on my webbrowser, the web page send me an error about incorrect parameters.. and yes!, MySQL is the responsible!

so.. Is there any help you can say me?

Answer (score 0):

You already have mysql installed at running.

On Debian/Ubuntu systems, you can just install whatever you need using `apt-get`, and most of it is already there. You don't really need xampp on a Debian based system, because you can do:

```
apt-get install apache2 php5 mysql phpmyadmin proftpd
```

And yes, php5 will be automatically enabled. And yes, you might have to do some manual configuration to enable some php modules.

The problem here is that the mysql version shipped with xampp is not the mysql that is already installed. You can `dpkg --remove mysql` and restart xampp.